# center value table with multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Hi please any suggestions to center the value of last line (R^2)
here my table and output

Tex:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,psfrag}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% caption fonts
 \usepackage[font={large,bf}]{caption} 

 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{threeparttable}  
 \usepackage{tabulary}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{array,multirow}

   \begin{document}

 \begin{landscape}
   \begin{table}[!ht]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Predictive regression estimation results, 1926:07-2021:02}
    \label{tab:table_segregation_occ_stats}
\resizebox{1.34\textwidth}{!}{
   \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
   \toprule
  \toprule
         & \multicolumn{ 4}{c}{\textbf{LASSO}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{OLS}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ OLS Post-LASSO
                                       }}  \\
                               \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
                              \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
                    \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
                 & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
          \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                  \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
                    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
                    \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
                      \cmidrule(lr){12-13}
             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}\\
            \cmidrule{2-13}
                              \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Consumer Nondurables  }   &-& -& -0,086& 0,51& -0,004& 0,966&-0,146& 0.27&-& -&-0,14&0,26\\

        \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Consumer Durables  }     &-&-&-0,055&0,41&-0,005&0,920&-0,07&0,29&-&-&-0,087&0,19\\
      \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Manufacturing    }       &-&-& -& -&-0,014&0.89&-0,070& 0.65&-&-&-&-\\
         \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Energy  }                &-0,094&0,01&-0,120&0.04&-0,112&0,009&-0,13&0.03&-0,12&0,001&-0,13&0,023\\
        \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Chemicals and Allied Products  }&-&-&-0,053&0.62&-0,066&0,433&-0,040&0.73&-&-&-0,05&0,61\\

         \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Business Equipment   }       &-&-&0,081& 0,16&0,009&0.83&0,10&0.14&-&-&0,097&0,098\\
       \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Telecom  }                   &-&-&-&-&-0,04&0,34&-0,002&0.97&-&-&-&-\\
            \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Utilities }                  &0,08&0,11&0,13&0.10&0,12&0,039&0,16&0,053&0,10&0,04&0,16&0,046\\
      \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Shops  }                     &0,052&0,31&0,21&0.04&0,092&0,21&0,25&0,017&0,058&0,25&0,25&0,013\\
           \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Healthcare, Medical Equipment, and Drugs   }&-&-&-0,117&0.14&0,006&0.91&-0,13&0,09&-&-&-0,13&0,094\\

         \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Money:Finance  }&0,054&0,32&0,176&0.04&0,094&0.14&0,20&0,027& 0,06& 0.20& 0,20& 0,016\\

          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Other  }        &-&-&-&-&0,015&0,85&0,055&0,65&-&-& -& -\\

                      \midrule
                \textit{$R^2$}               &3.03\%&&5.48\%&&3.45\%&&5.63\%&&3.16\%&&5.59\%&\\
                         &(1,21)&&(9,48)&&(1,39)&&(9,74)&&(1,27)&&(9,67)&\\
                    \bottomrule
                    \bottomrule\end{tabular}}%
          \end{center}
            {\footnotesize {%Data Source: \href{http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data library.html}} \\
                    Note:  The table reports OLS slope coefficient estimates and the $R^{2}$ 
      statistic for the predictive regression model selected by the LASSO. The regressand is the excess return for the industry portfolio in the column heading. The regressors are selected from the complete set of lagged industry excess returns in the first column. Each predictive regression
        model includes an intercept term. Bold (italicized bold) indicates significance at the 10\% (5\%) level according to conventional OLS post-LASSO t-statistics;  indicates that the lagged industry excess return was not selected by the LASSO. Parentheses report the \citet{campbell2008} measure of the proportional increase in average excess return for a mean-variance investor who utilizes return predictability when allocating between a given industry portfolio and risk-free bills. 
                 }}
              \end{table}
              \end{landscape}

                \end{document}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: You just need to use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{$R^2$}}`. See the answer posted below.

Comment: I guess, you want to horizontally center an entry such as `3.03\%` with respect to both columns "Coef."  and "P-value". If that's correct, use `\multicolumn{ 2}{c}{3.03\%}` just as you did in your combined column headers, such as "NoDur".

Comment: If you on the other hand are interested in vertically centering the text "R^2", you could use `\multirow{2}{*}{...}`.

Comment: Entirely unterlated to the alignment issue, but do not use `\resizebox` on a table. It will inevitably lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout your document.

Comment: @leandriis , Thanks my friend  for your guidance, if you find time, I would be thankful to you if you could provide me with the following suggestions as an answer,

Comment: In my opinion, you should use `threeparttable` for the note, so that it has the width of the table.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @haithem: I unfortunatly don't really understand which output you would like to achieve. Probably a sketh of the desired alignment would help clarify? Also, did you intentionally mix `,` and `.` decimal separators in your table?

Comment: @Bernard - If one uses a `tabular*` environment and sets its width to `\textwidth`, one can omit the `\centering` instruction and just typeset the legend as ordinary running text.

Comment: @Mico: I agree this is a possibility, but I preferred enabling line breaks with an `m` first column  and reducing the value of `tabcolsep`.

Comment: @leandriis thanks, I didn't pay attention to this error. Those are CSV outputs of 3 estimations using the R software.  they are by default with a comma. why I looked for is like the suggestion of Mico and Bernard.. centering the value of the R^2 of durable and non-durable Goods for the 3 estimations ( lasso, ols, ols-post lasso)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose this code, in which I used the `S` column type, from`siunitx` to align numbers on the decimal dot and nested the tabular in a `threeparttable` environment for the notes after the table. Also, I replaced the `l` column type in the first column with an `m` column to enable automatic line breaking for long cells.

A final remark: don't use `\resizebox` to make a table fit the page, as it leads to inconsistent font sizes. There are several other solutions. In particular, I reduced the font size to `footnotesize` for all the table contents, and used a smaller value for `\tabcolsep` (6 pt by default), which is useful in case you have many columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathbbol}
%\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,psfrag}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% caption fonts
\usepackage[font={large,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xurl, hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Predictive regression estimation results, 1926:07-2021:02}
      \label{tab:table_segregation_occ_stats}
        \begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}m{3cm}|*{6}{S[table-format=-1.3 ]S[table-format=1.3 ]}}
          \toprule
          \toprule
          & \multicolumn{ 4}{c}{\textbf{LASSO}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{OLS}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ OLS Post-LASSO}} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
 \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
 \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
 & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
 \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
 \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
 \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
 \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
 \cmidrule(lr){12-13}
%
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}\\
 \cmidrule{2-13}
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Consumer Nondurables } &{-}& {-}& -0,086& 0,51& -0,004& 0,966&-0,146& 0.27&{-} & {-} &-0,14&0,26\\
%
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Consumer Durables } &{-}&{-}&-0,055&0,41&-0,005&0,920&-0,07&0,29&{-} &{-} &-0,087&0,19\\
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Manufacturing } &{-} &{-} & {-} & {-} &-0,014&0.89&-0,070& 0.65&{-} &{-} &{-} &{-} \\
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Energy } &-0,094&0,01&-0,120&0.04&-0,112&0,009&-0,13&0.03&-0,12&0,001&-0,13&0,023\\
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Chemicals and Allied Products }&{-} &{-} &-0,053&0.62&-0,066&0,433&-0,040&0.73&{-} &{-} &-0,05&0,61\\
%
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Business Equipment } &{-} &{-} &0,081& 0,16&0,009&0.83&0,10&0.14&{-} &{-} &0,097&0,098\\
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Telecom } &{-} &{-} &{-} &{-} &-0,04&0,34&-0,002&0.97&{-} &{-} &{-} &{-} \\
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Utilities } &0,08&0,11&0,13&0.10&0,12&0,039&0,16&0,053&0,10&0,04&0,16&0,046\\
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Shops } &0,052&0,31&0,21&0.04&0,092&0,21&0,25&0,017&0,058&0,25&0,25&0,013\\
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Healthcare, Medical Equipment, and Drugs }&{-} &{-} &-0,117&0.14&0,006&0.91&-0,13&0,09&{-} &{-} &-0,13&0,094\\
%
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Money:Finance }&0,054&0,32&0,176&0.04&0,094&0.14&0,20&0,027& 0,06& 0.20& 0,20& 0,016\\
%
 \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Other } &{-} &{-} &{-} &{-} &0,015&0,85&0,055&0,65&{-} &{-} & {-} & {-} \\
%
 \midrule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{$R^2$}} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{3.03\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{5.48\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{3.45\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{5.63\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{3.16\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{5.59\%}\\
%
 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(1,21)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(9,48)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(1,39)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(9,74)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(1,27)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(9,67)}\\
 \bottomrule
 \bottomrule\end{tabular}%
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[\!] Data Source: \url{http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data library.html}\smallskip

\item[\!]Note: The table reports OLS slope coefficient estimates and the $R^{2}$
 statistic for the predictive regression model selected by the LASSO. The regressand is the excess return for the industry portfolio in the column heading. The regressors are selected from the complete set of lagged industry excess returns in the first column. Each predictive regression
 model includes an intercept term. Bold (italicized bold) indicates significance at the 10\% (5\%) level according to conventional OLS post-LASSO t-statistics; indicates that the lagged industry excess return was not selected by the LASSO. Parentheses report the \cite{campbell2008} measure of the proportional increase in average excess return for a mean-variance investor who utilizes return predictability when allocating between a given industry portfolio and risk-free bills.
 \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to suggest that you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabular*` environment and shorten some of contents of the first (left-hand-most) column. I'd also like to suggest that you load the `siunitx` package and use the package's `S` column type in order to align the numbers in the 12 data columns on their decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,psfrag}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{enumitem}

 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{threeparttable}  
 \usepackage{tabulary}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{array,multirow}
 \usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx} % <-- new

% handy short-cut macros:
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mcii[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mciv[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Predictive regression estimation results, 1926:07--2021:02}
\label{tab:table_segregation_occ_stats}

\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l 
     *{2}{S[table-format=-1.3]S[table-format=1.2]}
     *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3]S[table-format=1.3]} }
\toprule
& \mciv{LASSO} & \mciv{OLS} & \mciv{OLS Post-LASSO}  \\
\cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} \cmidrule{10-13}
 & \mcii{NonDur} & \mcii{Durbl} 
 & \mcii{NonDur} & \mcii{Durbl} 
 & \mcii{NonDur} & \mcii{Durbl} \\
   \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
   \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
   \cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-13}
&\mc{Coef.}&\mc{$p$-val}&\mc{Coef.}&\mc{$p$-val}
&\mc{Coef.}&\mc{$p$-val}&\mc{Coef.}&\mc{$p$-val}
&\mc{Coef.}&\mc{$p$-val}&\mc{Coef.}&\mc{$p$-val}\\
\cmidrule{2-13}
Consumer Nondurables &{--}&{--}& -0,086& 0,51& -0,004& 0,966&-0,146& 0.27&{--}&{--}&-0,14&0,26\\
Consumer Durables &{--}&{--}&-0,055&0,41&-0,005&0,920&-0,07&0,29&{--}&{--} &-0,087&0,19\\
Manufacturing &{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}&-0,014&0.89&-0,070& 0.65&{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}\\
Energy    &-0,094&0,01& -0,120&0.04&-0,112&0,009&-0,13&0.03&-0,12&0,001&-0,13&0,023\\
Chemicals and Allied Products &{--}&{--}&-0,053&0.62&-0,066&0,433&-0,040&0.73&{--}&{--}&-0,05&0,61\\
Business Equipment &{--}&{--}&0,081& 0,16&0,009&0.83&0,10&0.14&{--}&{--}&0,097&0,098\\
Telecom   &{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}&-0,04&0,34&-0,002&0.97&{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}\\
Utilities       &0,08&0,11&0,13&0.10&0,12&0,039&0,16&0,053&0,10&0,04&0,16&0,046\\
Shops  &0,052&0,31&0,21&0.04&0,092&0,21&0,25&0,017&0,058&0,25&0,25&0,013\\
Healthcare, Med.\ Equip., Drugs   &{--}&{--}&-0,117&0.14&0,006&0.91&-0,13&0,09&{--}&{--}&-0,13&0,094\\
Money: Finance  &0,054&0,32&0,176&0.04&0,094&0.14&0,20&0,027& 0,06& 0.20& 0,20& 0,016\\
Other   &{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}&0,015&0,85&0,055&0,65&{--}&{--}&{--}&{--}\\
\midrule
R\textsuperscript{2}  &\mc{3,03\%}&&\mc{5,48\%}&&\mc{3,45\%}&&\mc{5,63\%}&&\mc{3,16\%}&&\mc{5,59}\% &\\
       &\mc{(1,21)}&&\mc{(9,48)}&&\mc{(1,39)}&&\mc{(9,74)}&&\mc{(1,27)}&&\mc{(9,67)} &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
\textsc{Notes}:  The table reports OLS slope coefficient estimates and the $R^{2}$ statistic for the predictive regression model selected by the LASSO. The regressand is the excess return for the industry portfolio in the column heading. The regressors are selected from the complete set of lagged industry excess returns in the first column. Each predictive regression model includes an intercept term. Bold (italicized bold) indicates significance at the 10\% (5\%) level according to conventional OLS post-LASSO $t$-statistics;  indicates that the lagged industry excess return was not selected by the LASSO\@. Parentheses report the \citet{campbell2008} measure of the proportional increase in average excess return for a mean-variance investor who utilizes return predictability when allocating between a given industry portfolio and risk-free bills.
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,psfrag}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% caption fonts
\usepackage[font={large,bf}]{caption} 

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{center}
      \caption{Predictive regression estimation results, 1926:07-2021:02}
      \label{tab:table_segregation_occ_stats}
      \resizebox{1.34\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
          \toprule
          \toprule
          & \multicolumn{ 4}{c}{\textbf{LASSO}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{OLS}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ OLS Post-LASSO
                                                                                     }}  \\
          \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
          \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
          \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
          & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{NoDur} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Durbl} \\
          \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
          \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
          \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
          \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
          \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
          \cmidrule(lr){12-13}
          &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value}\\
          \cmidrule{2-13}
          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Consumer Nondurables  }   &-& -& -0,086& 0,51& -0,004& 0,966&-0,146& 0.27&-& -&-0,14&0,26\\

          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Consumer Durables  }     &-&-&-0,055&0,41&-0,005&0,920&-0,07&0,29&-&-&-0,087&0,19\\
          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Manufacturing    }       &-&-& -& -&-0,014&0.89&-0,070& 0.65&-&-&-&-\\
          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Energy  }                &-0,094&0,01&-0,120&0.04&-0,112&0,009&-0,13&0.03&-0,12&0,001&-0,13&0,023\\
          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Chemicals and Allied Products  }&-&-&-0,053&0.62&-0,066&0,433&-0,040&0.73&-&-&-0,05&0,61\\

          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Business Equipment   }       &-&-&0,081& 0,16&0,009&0.83&0,10&0.14&-&-&0,097&0,098\\
          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Telecom  }                   &-&-&-&-&-0,04&0,34&-0,002&0.97&-&-&-&-\\
          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Utilities }                  &0,08&0,11&0,13&0.10&0,12&0,039&0,16&0,053&0,10&0,04&0,16&0,046\\
          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Shops  }                     &0,052&0,31&0,21&0.04&0,092&0,21&0,25&0,017&0,058&0,25&0,25&0,013\\
          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Healthcare, Medical Equipment, and Drugs   }&-&-&-0,117&0.14&0,006&0.91&-0,13&0,09&-&-&-0,13&0,094\\

          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Money:Finance  }&0,054&0,32&0,176&0.04&0,094&0.14&0,20&0,027& 0,06& 0.20& 0,20& 0,016\\

          \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{Other  }        &-&-&-&-&0,015&0,85&0,055&0,65&-&-& -& -\\

          \midrule
          \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{$R^2$}}               &\multicolumn{2}{c}{3.03\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{5.48\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{3.45\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{5.63\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{3.16\%}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{5.59\%}\\
          &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(1,21)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(9,48)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(1,39)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(9,74)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(1,27)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(9,67)}\\
          \bottomrule
          \bottomrule\end{tabular}}%
    \end{center}
    {\footnotesize {%Data Source: \href{http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data library.html}} \\
        Note:  The table reports OLS slope coefficient estimates and the $R^{2}$ 
        statistic for the predictive regression model selected by the LASSO. The regressand is the excess return for the industry portfolio in the column heading. The regressors are selected from the complete set of lagged industry excess returns in the first column. Each predictive regression
        model includes an intercept term. Bold (italicized bold) indicates significance at the 10\% (5\%) level according to conventional OLS post-LASSO t-statistics;  indicates that the lagged industry excess return was not selected by the LASSO. Parentheses report the \cite{campbell2008} measure of the proportional increase in average excess return for a mean-variance investor who utilizes return predictability when allocating between a given industry portfolio and risk-free bills. 
      }}
  \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi, your suggestions do not  make the value-centered

Comment: @haithem see the edit

Comment: yes all the values of the last line in the table

Comment: Does the current version produce what you want?

Comment: thank you, that's what I'm looking for